# Did the Reinheitsgebot ever make it to Belgium?

Tags: history, german-beers

Did the Germanic purity laws ever make it to some of the other lowlands? If not why or did they have there own less famous purity laws? What exactly is the history behind it?

Comment: I don't think they ever made it to all of Germany :-) Interesting question though.

Comment: I don't think they know what it is in Belgium.

Answer (score 3):

**Did the Reinheitsgebot ever make it to Belgium?**

Reinheitsgebot never made over the entirety of Germany.

Wikipedia mentions that only that Greece and China incorporated these regulations on beer. Belgium remained free from the Reinheitsgebot regulatory laws concerning beer.

> Outside of Germany, the Reinheitsgebot was formally incorporated in Greek law by the first Greek king, Otto (originally a Bavarian prince). German brewers at the Tsingtao Brewery in the German colony in Qingdao, China also followed the law voluntarily. - [Reinheitsgebot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinheitsgebot)

Comment: Namibians also make a german purity law beer under the Windhoek Lager brand. That quote may be referring to old breweries though.